# Use process.env with Inversify

Tags: typescript, inversion-of-control, inversifyjs

I'm trying to comply to the IoC principle so I'm refactoring my TypeScript app before it's too big.

Things were going pretty good with Inversify so far but I stumbled on a question: "How to manage `process.env`?

Let me explain: I have a DataBase interface bound to a Firebase concretion in my composition root. But this concretion needs a "service account" (JSON with credentials in it). Before IoC, my main class was checking `process.env` and passing down the value to the concretion. Now it just feels wrong.

But what is the *right* way? I thought of creating a binding to a constant value (value of the JSON) but it seems to me I shouldn't set such an implementation-specific thing here. Should I read the `process.env` in the concretion?

Any leads will be welcome :)